# Acess stored data on protected variables on parent class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

Suppose i've got the following scenario:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        protected List<String> FooList = new List<string>();
        public void OperationsOnFoo()
        {
        //Some stuff who's going to add data to FooList
        }
    }

    public class Foo2 : Foo
    {
        public void Foo2Methods()
        {
        //I can access FooList but i can't get its data
        }
    }
}
```

The Form Part...

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        //Select Files

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

var InstanceOfFoo2 = new Foo2();
InstanceOfFoo2.Foo2Methods();
    }
```

I can aceess all variables and methods from Foo ; but i can't get access to the data stored on them.
Is there any way of doing  that (rather than setting public) , or should i pass the content to a public var and use it on the child class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're wanting to protect them from being *set*, and not *read* as you obviously have a need to read the values. Try the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<String> FooList { get; private set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        FooList = new List<string>();
    }

    public void OperationsOnFoo()
    {
        //Some stuff who's going to add data to FooList
    }
}

public class Foo2 : Foo
{
    public void Foo2Methods()
    {
        //Have fun getting the data here!
    }
}
```

Edit:

This is a working program. It displays the number of items, and each item in the list:

```
namespace ConsoleSandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Foo2();
            foo.OperationsOnFoo();
            foo.Foo2Methods();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public List<String> FooList { get; private set; }

        public Foo()
        {
            FooList = new List<string>();
        }

        public void OperationsOnFoo()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                FooList.Add(i.ToString());
            }

        }
    }

    public class Foo2 : Foo
    {
        public void Foo2Methods()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FooList.Count);

            foreach (var aString in FooList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(aString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before. Same behaviour. When i check the var inside Foo2 , it has 0 elements.

Comment: @PabloCosta I including a working Console program that uses the classes. I can access the count of items in FooList as well as all the values. See how it differs from your actual implementation.

Comment: please check the update i made. I added an example of whats going on.

Comment: The main difference in our implementations is that you're using public modifiers. I'm using protected ones.

Comment: @PabloCosta In your example you never call OperationsOnFoo(); which I assume is where you populate the values. I pulled my console example into a WPF form and it runs fine, just like with the console. Do you call OperationsOnFoo(); in your actual code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ibE7nSUG check here - both class and form code. You'll get what i mean.

Comment: Okay, yeah, that's exactly what is happening. You're new-ing up FileManipulation() with a new, empty ValidFiles of List<string>(), which has 0 elements. You never call any methods that would populate it. If I'm reading your code right you'd want to call SelectFiles(), and then OpenFiles(), and then ReadFiles(), and then FileDefiniton(), and finally ColorExtraction(). You don't even need to use my code.

Comment: Gotcha. I was thinking the same thing. But, i can't call all those methods twice ; they're being called on button1 event. Only on button5 is where i call the method ColorExtraction().

Comment: Hmm...unless i make a copy of 'em to some variable on the child class. That way i would have its elements.

Comment: You might consider making an instance of FileManipulation a form-class wide variable that you can then call methods on via your buttons. This would keep the information tied to it in place. When you need to restart/refresh the FileManipuation object, just new it up again (could tie this to a "restart" button).

Comment: I tought your idea would solve the problem but it didn't.  Inside    public partial class Form1 : Form i instantiated FileManipulation and used it on the other button - same thing, when Debugging, ValidFiles has 0 elements. And i know it has elements (debugged this also).

Comment: So I couldn't use exactly your code (I don't have the correct files on my machine to run) but this code does work, as long as you press the buttons  in the right order. Obviously you'll need to swap the business logic back to what you have it: http://pastebin.com/agQP2U4E

Comment: Interesting that we're doing the same thing but with different results. My code looks just like yours. I do instantiate the classes the way you do, the parent class works fine but the child class still looks like null. Since the question has changed i'll ask a new one. Thanks in advance for all the help !